# How many crows do I need to push someone?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic

After watching the newest [League of Legends Cinematic Trailer](https://youtu.be/tEnsqpThaFg?t=40) I became obsessed with the concept of shooting crows at a person, sending them flying, or even better shooting them at the ground in order to fly!

But, of course, this cannot be possible, right? Assuming that I am somehow able to create and shoot these crows: **How fast would I have to shoot how many of them in order to send someone flying? What about to send me flying?**

Comment: Related - [What is the airspeed of an unladed Swallow](https://youtu.be/y2R3FvS4xr4)

Comment: Technically speaking, the answer is a "Murder"

Comment: 1 frozen crow and an air cannon. This way it would truly be a murder of crows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the estimation, There are lots sub-species of crow, ranging from 0.68 kg to 4.4 kg per bird depending on the species, at maximum speed they fly about 35 to 56 km/hr. By shooting them at the ground in order to fly I think you mean something like a rocket, right?

Average momentum of each crow would be approx (115.5/60) 1.925 N. Assuming crows are generated magically (not worrying about carrying them with you) and flying at max speed, they can propel your average person of 80 kg.

You would need 784 N to stay flying. Roughly 407 crows per second. More if you want to fly upwards.